# Splitting byte list into position lists C#

Tags: c#

So I have a list of bytes

```
List<byte> s = {1,2,3,2,2,2,3,1,2,4,2,1,4,.....};
```

I want to get new position lists using index of element.To something like this...

```
List<byte> 1 = {0,7,11};
List<byte> 2 = {1,3,4,5,8,10};
List<byte> 3 = {2,6};
List<byte> 4 = {9,12};
List<byte> 5 = ..... and so on
```

What`s the best way of doing this?

thank you.

Comment: `1` is not a valid type identifier. (Neither are `2`, `3`, `4`, or `5`). I assume you meant `List<byte> listOf1s = ...` and so on?

Comment: My bad, fixed now, yes you are correct lc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary` to get `Dictionary<byte, List<int>>`:

```
var dict = s.Select((value, index) => new { value, index })
            .GroupBy(x => x.value)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.index).ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ, you can create an [`ILookup<TKey, TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  with the desired results like this:

```
var indicesByByte = s.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index } )
                     .ToLookup(tuple => tuple.Item, tuple => tuple.Index);
```

Now,

- `indicesByByte[0]` will be a sequence containing `{0,7,11}`
- `indicesByByte[1]` will be a sequence containing `{1,3,4,5,8,10}`
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is with LINQ, using the overload of `Enumerable<T>.Select` which contains the index, then grouping:

```
var groups = s.Select((item, index) => new {index, item})
              .GroupBy(x => x.item, x => x.index)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

This will return a `Dictionary<byte, List<int>>` where the key is the value (1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in your example) and the value contains a list of positions.

---

You could also do it using a for loop, in a single pass:

```
var groups = new Dictionary<byte, List<int>>();

for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
{
    if(!groups.ContainsKey(s[i]))
        groups[s[i]] = new List<int>();

    groups[s[i]].Add(i);
}
```